# Developer Survey 2018 - it is too long without saving

Tags: feature-request, survey-2018

Yesterday I saw that there is a developer survey. I decided to spend like 15 minutes on it but found that I did not even pass 50% of it but became too tired to continue. I closed the browser and shut down the computer. Today I opened it again and I must pass the whole quiz again, from the beginning. I propose the survey to remember all the progress because it is **too** long and many people may just not want to spend a 30 minutes on it. Now when I opened it today and found that I must start it from the beginning, I lost my enthusiasm to pass it again.

Comment: Just leave it open? I'm really annoyed by those expiring tokens on surveys when you get called away for 20 minutes when you were half through but SO does *that* right. The "save" is to just not power down your PC. You can put it in suspend or something.

Comment: @nvoigt At first, I wanna shut down my pc before going to the bed, and the second, I switched PC's (I started it on the home pc but tried to continue on the work pc). This should be saved as `account -> progress` way, not `opened tab -> progress`.

Comment: hm, I have never seen a survey working the way you'd like. That seems a lot of extra effort. Do you know surveys that do it that way? Sidenote: there are questions asking about the length of the survey itself... but naturally, they are at the end.

Comment: @nvoigt I am not ready to tell which surveys exactly can do this but I am 500% sure I saw such surveys.

Comment: Maybe link to one. I'm not sure about this year because I don't use that feature, but the survey used to be anonymous, with your ID optional at the end... it's kinda hard to save data for people that are anonymous, you'd need to register *another* account just for the survey.

Comment: @nvoigt I don't pass quizes 10 times in a day, sorry, I can't provide such links :) But I don't remember, whether they worked after switching PCs or not.

Comment: *500%* is a very specific arbitrary relative length value :) The survey does feel arduous to me, I took it initially with the false assumption that it it would be quick one (this was the first survey I've taken). An "average completion time" may be helpful, so that folks don't progress 15 minutes in, lose patience, and drop off. In regards to saving progress, I can't see why this couldn't be done with `sessionStorage`

Comment: Good surveys mention in the beginning approximately how long it will take to complete. I think this one was too long as well, but at least they removed the "joke questions" from previous years.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError To be fair, the survey does say to set aside 30 minutes right at the beginning.

Comment: @BSMP Now that you've mentioned that, I do seem to recall, albeit *vaguely* :/ I propose a name change: "Take the {year} 30 min(+/-) Developer Survey" :)